# Jquery show/hide

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I've got the following code:

```
$('#hideButton').click(function() {
        $('#menu').animate({
            opacity: 0.25
            });
        $('#hideButton').val('Show');
        $('#hideButton').attr('id','showButton');
    });

    $('#showButton').click(function() {
        $('#menu').animate({
            opacity: 1
            });
        $('#showButton').val('Hide');
        $('#showButton').attr('id','hideButton');
    });
```

As you see `#hideButton` should reduce div opacity to 0.25 and then change it's id to showButton. When I click showButton it should increase the div opacity to 1 but for some reason the code isn't working after clicking the changed button.

Comment: It won't work, because when first run, the runtime doesn't find any `#showButton` on you page, hence no action will be performed.

Comment: You may want to look into `.toggle()` instead: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: why using opacity. will it be good with IE x. why dont you simply use .show and .hide  or addClass removeClass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not modify the IDs and would just go off of the value of the button to determine which action should be taken:

```
$('#hideButton').click(function() {         
    var ele = $(this);
    if(ele.val() == "Hide"){ 
        ele.val('Show');
        $('#menu').animate({ opacity: 0.25 }); 
    }else{
        ele.val('Hide');
        $('#menu').animate({ opacity: 1 });
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rt4QY/

Answer (score 2):

The events are bound to the elements when they are loaded. When they are loaded, there is no element with the id showbutton, so that doesn't get attached to anything. Instead, you should put an if statement in your hide function to check the val() of the button. If it is "hide" do your hide functionality, if it is "show" do the show.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't change your button's ID**. Rather work with CSS classes.

The problem you're having you're setting a click handler to a button with ID `showButton`, that doesn't exists at the moment when you're binding click event to it. Your button will become available after you've clicked your `hideButton` because that will convert it to `showButton`.

Since this is the same DOM element you should rather use CSS classes and keep ID as it is initially. I would suggest (and other would hopefully agree) that changing IDs is bad practice in the first place and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

By changing IDs, you're probably ripping the event handler out from under jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the previous answers that changing the ID is not the best approach. But, if you want to get your click handlers to work, use the `live` function instead of `click`:

```
$('#hideButton').live('click', function() {
  // function body same as before
});
$('#showButton').live('click', function() {
  // same as before
}
```

Note that the use of `live` will also work if you are trying to change the element's class instead of ID.